# Playframework - ISO format date with timezone in request query param is incorrectly parsed

Tags: scala, playframework, jodatime

Why the following iso format date is parsed incorrectly?

```
GET /find?account.create_date=2016-06-01T00:00:00.000+05:45
```

In the controller, if I print the `queryString`, I get the following result:

```
println(request.queryString)
//result - Map(account.create_date -> Buffer(2016-06-01T00:00:00.000 05:45))
```

As, you can see, the timezone sign is missing `05:45` instead of `+05:45`. However, negative timezone work well. `2016-06-01T00:00:00.000-05:45` is successfully parsed as it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the ISO date format is not compliant with the URL encoding (RCF-3896 which has a special use for space and : characters). Playframework will be automatically URL decoding the querystrings you pass in the URL for you.

The correct date time string should have been

```
GET /find?account.create_date=2016-06-01T00%3A00%3A00.000%2B05%3A45
```

You can read more about the URL encoding here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding